# How to drag and drop inside a container in React?

Tags: reactjs, drag, drop

I'm trying to drag and drop card components which are rendered inside a `div` element of the parent component. These cards should only be allowed to be dragged inside this `div` container and only in some particular positions.

I have tried using onDragStart, onDrag and onDragEnd functions to do so and I could manage to drag the components around the web. The problem is that I don't know how to configure the dragged components to  be dragged only inside the `div` container and only in particular positions.

Here is an example of my parent component where the draggable cards are being rendered:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import ExperienceCards from '../ExperienceCards';
import experienceData from '../../Data/experienceData';

const Home = () => {

    const experienceCards = experienceData.map((card, i) => 
        <div key={i} className="mt-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
            {/* <p className="card-index">{i + 1}</p> */}
            <div className="w-90">
                <ExperienceCards 
                    title={card.title} 
                    text={card.text} 
                    time={card.time} 
                    showIcon={card.showIcon} 
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );


    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
                <div className="col-md-2 aside-bg pt-3 pb-3">
                    <div className="aside-container">
                        <h3 className="aside-title">Experiencias</h3>   
                        <Button icon={ <AddIcon /> } />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {experienceCards}
                    </div>
                </div>
               
      //SOME OTHER COMPONENTS

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

And this is an example of the draggable cards:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import MoreVertIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreVert';
import Select from '../Select';

const ExperienceCards = ({ title, text, time, showIcon }) => {
    const [x, setX] = useState(0);
    const [y, setY] = useState(0);

    const handleDragStart = (event) =>{
        console.log("Started")
    }

    const handleDrag = (event) =>{
        console.log("Dragging...")
    }

    const handleDragEnd = (event) =>{
        setX(event.clientX);
        setY(event.clientY);
    }   

    return(
        <div 
            draggable
            onDragStart={handleDragStart}
            onDrag={handleDrag}
            onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
            style={{
                position: "absolute",
                left: x,
                top: y
            }}
            className="card-container p-3"
        >
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between mb-1">
                <h6 className="card-title w-75">{title}</h6>
                {showIcon && <MoreVertIcon />}
            </div>
            <p className="card-text color-muted mt-2">{text}</p>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline mt-3">
                <p className="card-time color-muted">{time}</p>
                <Select />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ExperienceCards;
```

Is there any way to do so?

I tried setting changing the styles of the `div` container to position relative but it didn't work.

Here is an image of my web:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

kindly use the npm package of react js.
here is the link.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable

Comment: I could manage to solve it using a library called: react-beautiful-dnd. Thanks for the recomendation anyways